# How do I group consecutive dates within a Vector in R?

Tags: r, date, vector

I have a vector of dates below;

```
dates <- c("2018-05-16", "2018-07-20", "2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "2018-07-21", "2018-07-22", "2018-05-17")
```

I want to group the consecutive dates together. Is this possible to do?

I.e I want the dates "2018-05-16" & "2018-05-17" in one group, "2018-07-20",  "2018-07-21" & "2018-07-22" in another group and finally "2018-06-25" & "2018-06-26" in another group.

Through doing some research online I found that I may have to use the following code below;

```
dateGroups <- c(NA,diff(as.Date(dates))==1)
```

However I am not sure.

Comment: Do you need `split(dates, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(dates)) == 1)))`

Comment: @akrun So your code splits the dates, but not into consecutive groups unfortunately

Comment: Please update your post with expected so that others will not be confused\

Comment: @akrun done! Let me know if it still doesn't make sense please.

Comment: Please check the solution posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to `sort` and then do the comparison

```
dates1 <- sort(as.Date(dates))
split(dates1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dates1) != 1)))
#$`1`
#[1] "2018-05-16" "2018-05-17"

#$`2`
#[1] "2018-06-25" "2018-06-26"

#$`3`
#[1] "2018-07-20" "2018-07-21" "2018-07-22"
```

---

The above `split` into a `list` of `vector`s.  If we need a `data.frame` with a grouping column

```
df1 <- data.frame(dates1, group = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dates1) != 1)))
```

Comment: Sorry one last question. Isit possible to take the latest date in each group? I.e 2018-05-17 in group 1, 2018-06-26 in group 2 and 2018-07-22 in group 3?

Comment: @Jed Sure, `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(dates = max(dates1))`